# how to access thread/busy thread counts within a Java EE filter under tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, multithreading

I'd like to access my servlet container's thread/busy thread counts within a filter under tomcat.

Is this a part of the Java EE standard? Or does it have to be tomcat specific? Is there a more general server load measurement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will definitely be server specific, and quite possibly also different between versions. Additionally the application server could not allow you (I mean your web-app) to access this type of information, but if this is the case it is probably dependent on your security setup.

You could try to get this information via JMX, although I don't think it was meant for this scenario. In Tomcat 6 the Executor status should be exposed via JMX.